# Firestore return all documents in collection at the root

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

At the root of my firestore db I have a 'users' and 'accounts' collections.
Whenever I try to return all documents in either of those collection I get an error (there is definitely data there):

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Null value error. for 'list' @ L59, Null value error. for 'list' @ L63, Null value error. for 'list' @ L76

Code to produce above error:

```
const query = fs.query(
     fs.collection(firestore, 'accounts'),
  );

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query);

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
```

If I try and return all documents from any sub collection it works fine:

```
const query = fs.query(
     fs.collection(firestore, `accounts/${accountId}`, 'sites'),
  );

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query);

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
```

Any ideas why this would be, am I querying wrong? Could it be something to do with firestore rules?

Ta.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue I've found the cause.

I just disabled all rules in firestore.rules (created by someone else) and added a general rule to access all documents if authenticated:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

This then stopped the error and listed all documents.

Comment: Security rules would never cause javascript errors like the one you show.  The worst that would ever happen with a security rule is that a query would be rejected and cause an error on the call to `getDocs` that says "Missing or insufficient permissions". That is the only error that could ever happen as a result of a security rule configuration.